# Typescript typecheck not working on Http post response

Tags: angular, typescript, typechecking, angular-httpclient

I have this Http Call:

```
getSomething(): Observable<MyTypedClass> {
return this.httpClient.post<MyTypedClass>(this._url, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.formatErrors)
  );
```

}

Where MyTypedClass.ts look like this:

```
export class MyTypedClass {
  code: string;
  state: string;
}
```

JSON Response (Missmatch MyTypedClass):

```
{ "code": "INF00001", "test":true }
```

Since my JSON response does not match MyTypedClass for test purposes.

**Question**: Should I expect the HttpClient throws some missmatch or parse error and fires the error function on subscribers?

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript's type system in for compile-time only. It guides how you write your code, and is erased at runtime. You won't get any errors at runtime for JSON data not matching your class.